# How do I calculate the indefinite integral with a square root?

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

For example, how do I calculate the indefinite integral of the square root of x? I understand how the power rule works, but im confused by the square root.

I would appreciate any help given!

Comment: write $\sqrt{x}=x^{1/2}$. Then the power-rule works fine.

Comment: Is the square root of anything just x^1/2?

Comment: for any positive, real number $x$. Yes.

Comment: @AlanPiggott Several of your questions on this site suggest that you are struggling with basic algebra (dividing fractions, laws of exponents) and trying to learn calculus at the same time. That will be very difficult. Perhaps you should find a good compact review book for the algebra (on line or hard copy) and work through it quickly to get up to speed on prerequisites.

Answer (score 1):

Well, note that:
$$\sqrt{x}\equiv x^{1/2}$$
Now applying the [Power Rule](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_rule#Power_rule) should work fine:
$$\int x^n~dx=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}+C$$
Where $n\neq -1$.

Combine these two results to evaluate your integral.